# Going to or I will

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

I’m puzzled with going to vs I will in these sentences.

1. I’m going to always love you.
2. I will always love you.

What sounds better? But I do believe that “going to” implies I haven’t yet loved you but I will with intentions. And saying “I will” implies that I will continue loving you moving forward on in time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We would normally say, "I'm always going to love you" rather than "I'm going to always love you", which sounds awkward and which also breaks a rule of grammar concerning **split infinitives**. People care less about these than they used to, but [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/split-infinitives) says it is safer to avoid them in formal writing.

"I'm always going to love you" and "I will always love you" mean exactly the same.

Perhaps "I will always love you" sounds more elegant.